# SwiftUI - How to format Firestore Timestamp in a TextView

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, timestamp, swiftui

I have a startTime field returned from Firestore which is defined as a timestamp.  I am using Codable to specify startTime as a date in Swift.

I cannot see how to convert the full date provided by timestamp to just a time.

Text("\(startTime)" gives me "Monday, September 7, 2020 at 12:00:00 PM British Summer Time"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following example as reference to get the format you want

```
 let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
 dateFormatter.dateFormat = "HH:mm"
 let newDateString = dateFormatter.string(from: yourDate)
```

[Here](https://nsdateformatter.com/) you can find the different format options.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a more complete (ready to use) answer:

```
import Foundation
import FirebaseFirestore

func formatTransactionTimpestamp(_ timestamp: Timestamp?) -> String {
  if let timestamp = timestamp {
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateStyle = .short
    dateFormatter.timeStyle = .short
     
    let date = timestamp.dateValue()
    dateFormatter.locale = Locale.current
    let formatted = dateFormatter.string(from: date)
    return formatted
  }
  return ""
}
```

- [Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/dateformatter)
- [Firebase docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/node/firebase.firestore.Timestamp#todate)